# Bootstrap - Jekyll: Forbidden - no access permission to `/'

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-12.04, ruby, jekyll

I'm doing a tutorial on Twitter Bootstrap and apparently I need to install Jekyll for this. I've followed the installation procedure, but now I'm stuck getting Jekyll to work. In the terminal (Ubuntu 12.04) I start up Jekyll with the command `jekyll serve` (normal user, not root). This is the output in the terminal:

```
$ jekyll serve
Configuration file: none
            Source: /home/tester/workspaces/jekyll
       Destination: /home/tester/workspaces/jekyll/_site
      Generating... done.
    Server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

It seems to start up, but when I visit the page `http://0.0.0.0:4000`, I get the following error:

```
Forbidden
no access permission to `/'
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2011-10-30) at 0.0.0.0:4000
```

I've tried to bind to localhost, but that didn't make a difference:

```
jekyll serve -H 127.0.0.1
```

So it seems like the webserver is running. If I start jekyll as root, no change. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

```
Configuration file: none
```

the problem is here. that folder doesn't contain a config file which probably not init jekyll yet.

Comment: Please expand upon your answer—this isn't very useful as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial forgot about creating a new site.

```
cd /home/tester/workspaces/jekyll
jekyll new testsite
cd testsite
jekyll serve
```

Now I can open the new site in `http://0.0.0.0:4000`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because my site hadn't built properly. Check to see if there's an `index.html` in the `_site`

Answer (score -2):

If you had created and modified, then the reason is that you must be in the directory where you have the project and then there if
$jekyll serve